# Area lights turns off depending on camera angle / position (HDRP)

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I'm using the last version of Unity with HDR Pipeline and encounter a strange issue. Depending on the angle and proximity of my camera to an area lights, these will switch off for no reason (screens below).

On the below example, both of the area lights are set to "Mixed".

I tried with a spot light and did not encounter this issue.

What could cause the problem? I remember that I had this issue before on normal Unity version, and solved it by setting the light as "important" - unfortunately this option does not seem to be present in HDRP.

Thanks!

[image: Ok][image: not ok]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your quality settings, Unity will typically only allow a certain number of "active" lights at any given time. I believe setting a light to be "important" was a way to tell Unity not to disable that particular light. If you change your project's quality settings, you should be able to increase the number of allowed lights to a point where Unity won't have to disable any lights.